# GWT 2.2.0 Issue with updated IE and Windows 10

Tags: gwt

I am currently facing an issue with running GWT 2.2.0 on IE in Windows 10.

GWT plugin is installed and the application is compiled and launched successfully from eclipse end but still it won't run on IE. It shows error - "Can’t reach this page
•Make sure the web address http://127.0.0.1:8888 is correct"

IE Version- 32 bit-11.402.16299.0
Java- 32-bit-1.7
Eclipse Luna
GWT-2.2.0
OS-Windows 10

Can anyone please help with this issue? Does GWT 2.2.0 not supoorted by update Windows 10 and updated IE11 versions anymore?

Comment: DO NOT USE CLASSIC DEV MODE, ever, for any circumstance. Switch to super dev, or even better, codeserver. (you may need to update GWT, but trust me, it's the right thing to do)

Comment: C'mon, GWT 2.2 is more than 7 years old!